# Convert existing rails column from string to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, migration

I've an existing rails application and one of column's has existing `semi-colon separated string`. I want to convert the same into an array with an `empty array` as default.

Also, for rows which already have data in the `semi-colon separated string` format we need it to get converted into a proper array.

- Database: `psql` or `PostgreSQL`
- Framework: `Rails 4.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above is a pretty common scenario in development of any application and a lot of people face problems while doing the same in Rails.

In my opinion the easiest way to get all this done is:

1. Generate a new migration : `rails g migration changeSomethingToArray`
2. In the new migration file, add the following code.

   ```
   class ChangeQualificationToArray < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     rename_column :coaches, :qualifications, :qualifications_text
     add_column :coaches, :qualifications, :text, default: []

     coaches = Coach.all
     coaches.each do |c|
       c.qualifications = convert_to_array(c.qualifications_text)
       c.save
     end

     remove_column :coaches, :qualifications_text

   end

   private

   def convert_to_array(string)
     string.split(';')  
     # This can be changed to `,` or  whatever you're using to split your string.
   end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

```
class ChangeQualificationToArray < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    change_column :coaches, :qualifications, "varchar[] USING (string_to_array(qualifications, ';'))"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it efficiently, is by using PSQL query directly as follows:

```
class ChangeQualificationToArray < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TABLE "coaches" ALTER COLUMN "qualifications" TYPE text[] USING string_to_array("coaches"."qualifications", ',')::text[];
    SQL
  end
end
```